# Are the emails sent from a PHP and APACHE server stored somewhere?

Tags: apache, email

We ran into a problem where the emails from a contact form in a website weren't sent outside the server.

This shouldn't be a problem if the company's mail was hosted by us, but in this case it wasn't. So for two days they haven't received their mails.

My question is, is there a log or backup with the emails sent somewhere in Apache??

Comment: Not in apache. If any logs exist, they'll be located in whatever email server the hosting company operates, and there are a few.

Comment: There is a log in /var/log/mail.info of email sent, but only the recipient address is stored, not the email content.

Comment: There *may be* a log in `/var/log/mail.info`.  There is no guarantee that your system mailer is keeping logs there (or at all), and from this question it's not even possible to determine if the application is using a local mailer or a remote smtp server.  The answer is "it depends", and the only way to answer it is by expecting your application and system configuration.